Understanding some things about the $\mathcal S_i$
Take the $1$-parameter real analytic Schwartz class $\phi_s(x)=e^{\frac{s}{\log x}}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $s>0$ where if $s_1 s_2=1$ then $\phi_{s_1}\sim \phi_{s_2}$ (is glued) s.t. $\phi_{s_1}$ and $\phi_{s_2}$ are upper and lower bounds, and enclose regions $R_{s_1,s_2}$ in $(0,1)^2$, where $R_{s_1,s_2}$ is decorated with $\phi_s(x)$ $\forall s$ s.t. $s_1\le s\le s_2.$ We glue by taking $y_k=x+k$ for $k\in(-1,1)$ and gluing opposite points along these lines. Then the quotient spaces, the surfaces $\mathcal S_i$, are cylindrical.
A depiction of the setup before we construct the quotient

However it is advantageous to re-interpret the Schwartz class as an unnormalized pdf whereby computing its Fisher metric we obtain a Riemannian metric that gauges distances between curves with different parameters. The Fisher metric, which can be presented in closed form is $ F_s(t).$ By observation we note that $F_s(t)=\int_{I}\phi_s(x)x^{t-1}~dx$ where the RHS is a Mellin transform on bounded support. In other words the Fisher metric yields the same result as the Mellin transform. Therefore we pivot to the Mellin transform because we can leverage the fact that $F_s(t)$ is convergent for $\Re(t)>0$ in $\Bbb C$.
$$ F_s(t)=\int_I \phi_s(x)x^{t-1}dx=2\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}K_1(2\sqrt{st}) $$
for $K_1$ modified Bessel function.
One of the $\mathcal S_i$ pictured, sitting in an abstract space irrespective of a specific embedding

A possible embedding (pictured for only one) of one of the $\mathcal S_i$ within $(0,1)^3$

Since $F_s(t)$ was the Riemannian metric obtained thru Mellin/Fisher, we can form $(\mathcal S_i,g_s)$ where $g_s=F_s(t)_{\mathrm {quotient}}$. This is a $1$-parameter family of complex quotient metrics on cylindrical surfaces. I want to assume these surfaces form a partition so they should not intersect or overlap. Therefore we should have embeddings $e_i: \mathcal S_i \hookrightarrow (0,1)^3 $ s.t. $e_i(0,1)=1$ and $e_i(1,0)=0$ $\forall i$. The $\mathcal S_i$ are mutually diffeomorphic to $C=S^1\times (0,1)$. It is valid to unwrap the diffeomorphism to $C$ and further to an open annulus, further to $M=(0,1)^2 - \lbrace 1 ~\mathrm {point} \rbrace$ but it isn't necessary. Looking at $M$ has the advantage that the Schwartz class $\phi_s(x)$ can be mapped to rays on $M$ emanating from the puncture point, and the straight lines $y_k$ that were used to perform the gluing get mapped to concentric circles with the center being the puncture point.
In essence, this new formulation says that the $\mathcal S_i$ picture is equivalent to stacked punctured planes, $\Bbb C - \lbrace 1~\mathrm {point} \rbrace$, particularly amenable to complex rotations in $\Bbb C$. Of course $g_s$ would need to be transported onto the cylinders then the punctured complex planes via the respective mappings.
It would be illuminating to transport $g_s(t)$ via two succesive biholomorphisms onto the class $\Bbb C - \lbrace 1~\mathrm{point} \rbrace$ because in some ways this class is much simpler to work with.
We can remark that dynamics are available to us as well. $\phi_s(x)$ satisfies a second order linear partial differential equation, a diffusion equation
$$ s\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\phi_s(x)=-x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi_s(x)$$
and $F_s(t)$ satisfies a linear third order partial differential equation
$$  s^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial s^3} F_s(t)=t^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F_s(t) $$
reminiscent of the (non-singular) water wave pde used to understand shallow water dynamics.
The first pde suggests that the Schwartz class under the quotient evolves over the $\mathcal S_i$ in periodic motion (think rotating a string around the surface with fixed ends like a jump-rope). I don't know the form of this pde yet. The projection onto the base space, $R_{s_1,s_2}$ in $(0,1)^2$ recovers the diffusion we observed before constructing the quotient surfaces $\mathcal S_i$. The second pde suggests the metric is dynamical as well. Notice how these pde's live on the base space only, and haven't been built on the quotient surfaces $\mathcal S_i$ yet.
Because it is Schwartz, one can associate $\phi_s(x)$ to a $1$-parameter family of symmetric functional equations for the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(\cdot)$. Under the quotient this implies that this family of functional equations can be associated to the $\mathcal S_i$ giving rise to a dynamical and analytic structure on the $\mathcal S_i$ surfaces. The functional equations associated to $\phi_s(x)$ before the quotient is constructed are
$$\Gamma(\phi,s,t)\cdot \zeta(t) = \Gamma(\hat{\phi},s,1-t)\cdot \zeta(1-t)$$
where $$\Gamma(\phi,s,t)=\int_I \phi_s(x)x^{t-1}dx=F_s(t)$$
and $\hat \phi$ is the Fourier transform of $\phi$ on $(0,1)$.

What is the effect of the quotient space construction on the family of functional equations? Is there a geometric way to understand it?

Now the $1$-parameter family of functional equations is associated to the cylindrical surfaces $\mathcal S_i$ and a projection sends the $\mathcal S_i$ onto the $\phi_s(x)$ i.e. the $\mathcal S_i$ are double covers. The functional equations associated to $\phi_s(x)$ are essentially shadows of the ones after the quotient is constructed.
The functional equations I listed above, are based on $\phi_s(x)$ living on a flat space, whereas the quotient implies the new functional equation should be associated to curves on curved surfaces, the cylindrical $\mathcal S_i$.
